# Adding a view between contents inside a Webview

Tags: android, webview, admob

I am working on a newsreader app in which we have a Webview to display news details. Can I add an Admob layout between the contents inside this webview?

Basically, it should look like this,

```
-Webview
   -Paragaraph1
   -Admob layout
   -Paragraph2
-Webview
```

There should be only one webview and the Admob layout should be inside the webview, placed between content.

I tried with splitting the html content and loading them in multiple webviews inside a Recyclerview. But its affecting the performance a lot.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't possible and also it isn't a good practice as you are adding your ads on someone else's data.

And if it is your data you can always change the HTML page